# Why am I getting "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" on one line, but not a similar line just previous?

Tags: excel, vba

BLUF: Getting the above error on a line attempting to set a Range variable via named range. Errored line is a second of 3 similar statements, and first line executes just fine.

Overview: I'm creating a sign-in kiosk with a queue system that allows for multiple users to have a "queueView" userform open, while another workstation has the "signInFrm" userform open. The feature I am currently working on is a userform that will allow a user to view the log and filter/sort data. No big deal, was working perfectly until I tested the shared functionality, and found out that a shared Excel file cannot use AdvancedFilters (integral to my reports system). My solution was to have the reportsButton_Click event create a new Excel workbook, copy the needed sheets (Log and Search), and search/manipulate the temporary workbook.

I've been slowly figuring out how to make sure the userform is actually interacting with the correct workbook, but I've now run into the above problem. I am setting the ranges for use in the AdvancedFilter, and as stated above, the second statement generates the error, despite being essentially identical to the first. I have verified everything is spelled correctly, and the named range exists in the temp workbook, so I'm at a loss. I've seen some forum answers indicating that not only do you have to specify the worksheet (I've used a 'With tempSearch' block to mitigate that), but also the cells.. how do I do that with named ranges?

I have tried using .Activate on the specific worksheet (which is a Worksheet variable set to the specific workbook and sheet), but that doesn't seem to help. I've put the applicable code below, please let me know if more is needed.

```
'<WITHIN MY LOGSEARCH SUB>
'attempt to see what's happening
tmpSearch.Activate 'tmpSearch is a Worksheet variable set to the temp workbook's 'Search' sheet.

With tmpSearch
     'gather the search criteria
     'pastes the values gathered from userform into sheet to populate the AdvancedFilter using
     ' '.Cells(2,18).Value = variable' statement
     
     Set critRng = .Range("myCriteria")  'this line executes correctly
     Set dataRng = .Range("logSearchRng")  'this line generates the error
     Set resultRng = .Range("copyToRng")
End With
```

It's one of my biggest VBA projects, so it's kinda hard to lay out the whole structure, but my git repo is [here](https://github.com/vypr907/supportQ/tree/reports)

EDIT: So thank you to BigBen for giving me my lightbulb moment! The range that was erroring was referring to a different sheet, thus, errored out when in the `tmpSearch` `With` block. Moved that statement to it's own `With` block (`tmpLog`) and voila! Issue resolved!

Comment: Are you sure that named range is on the `tmpSearch` worksheet?

Comment: @BigBen I am sure, I've verified a few times, as the whole reports "stack" creates the spreadsheet and copies over the two sheets (along with the named ranges) every time it's run.

Comment: Checked your workbook: `logSearchRng` refers to the `Log` sheet? https://i.stack.imgur.com/slZqy.png

Comment: unfortunately, no trailing spaces.  and yes, it refers to the `Log` sheet. it's supposed to be telling the advancedFilter where to look for data

Comment: *potential lightbulb* could it be because it's attempting to access a sheet that is not "active"? O_O

Comment: No.... it's because, unless I have the wrong workbook, that range is on the "Log" sheet, not the "Search" one (screenshot in a previous comment)

Comment: so you're wrong, and you're right lol... the `With` block was for the `Search` sheet, thus, no workie. Put it in it's own `With` block, and it's back to working!  I appreciate your help!!


Also... am I allowed to submit my own answer, so the question will show as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BigBen who pointed out where the ranges were actually coming from!

The solution was moving the offending statement to it's own `With` block, referencing the correct Worksheet, as such:

```
With tmpSearch
    Set critRng = .Range("myCriteria")
    Set resultRng = .Range("copyToRng")
End With
With tmpLog
    Set dataRng = .Range("logSearchRng")
End With
```